# Tail Armature acting weird, how do I fix it?

Tags: mesh, armature, parent, inverse-kinematics

Followed this tutorial in rigging, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjSUjiD-SvI&ab_channel=RicSanCustomToys whole body works well. Trex tail (when I select any of the three last armatures) does not move correctly.

The other dino works just right, but I am unsure what went wrong as they were both rigged simultaneously, as in the two were rigged the same, or so I thought. I am unsure how to find the problem, where should I look/try?[image]

Comment: Please provide blend file so we can check out your settings. Screenshot isn’t that helpful here

Comment: Try connecting the bones in Edit mode. Choose the very tip bone, then the second last bone and hit `ctrl-p` to set it as parent and choose `connected`. Repeat with the second last and third-last bone.